# Как сделать с помощью циклов прямоугольник из проблелов и звездочек на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, консоль, символы, рисование

Как сделать с помощью циклов прямоугольник из пробелов и звездочек на `JavaScript`?

> Важно: без repeat, функций, массивов, объектов.

Answer (score 5):

Пример. Вывод в консоль.

```js
var horizCount = 10;
var vertCount = 5;
var str = '*'.repeat(10);

console.log(str);

for (var i=0; i < vertCount - 2; ++i) {
  console.log('*' + (' '.repeat(horizCount - 2)) + '*');
}

console.log(str);
```

---

Пример 2, чуть изменен. Условие вывода и вывод находятся внутри блока цикла.

```js
var horizCount = 10;
var vertCount = 5;
var fullstr = '*'.repeat(10);

for (var i = 0; i < vertCount; ++i) {
  var str = (i == 0 || i == vertCount - 1) ? fullstr : '*' + (' '.repeat(horizCount - 2)) + '*';     
  console.log(str);  
}
```

---

Вариант, где:

> без repeat, функций, массивов, объектов.

```js
var horizCount = 10;  // определяем сколько символов будет занимать по горизонтали
var vertCount = 5;    // определяем сколько символов будет занимать по горизонтали
var star = '*';       // символ звездочки
var whitespace = ' '; // символ пробела

// Делаем цикл сколько надо всего линий сделать по вертикали
for (var i = 0; i < vertCount; ++i) {
    var str = '';

    // если это первая линия или последняя, то рисуем чисто звездочки
    if (i == 0 || i == vertCount - 1) {    
      for (var j = 0; j < horizCount; ++j) {
        str += star;
      }    
    // если это ряд в середине, то в начале и конце рисуем звезды
    // а в середине - пробелы
    } else {
      str = star;
      for (var j = 0; j < horizCount - 2 ; ++j) {
        str += whitespace;
      }    
      str += star;
    }
    // вывод на консоль итога
    console.log(str);    
}
```

Comment: Блин, у строк же уже есть repeat)

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл написать, что без repeat, функций, массивов, объектов. Я ещё не дошел до этого.

Comment: `str` не нужен - сразу выводи все :-)

Comment: @Grundy для наглядности прост

Comment: @Bodrov `без repeat, функций, массивов, объектов.` - самый последний вариант

Comment: @vp_arth сам в шоке)) но предварительно проверил в гугле)

Comment: "i == vertCount - 1" почему здесь 5, а не 4?

Comment: @Bodrov потому что цикл начинается с нуля... в итоге будет 0 1 2 3 4 = итого 5 чисел.......или я что-то не понял?))

Comment: А почему "j < horizCount - 2" , ответьте пожалуйста. Мне дальше ромб и треугольники писать, думаю не потяну без вашего ответов.

Comment: @Bodrov потому что у прямоугольника, в данном случае, если это не верхняя и нижняя сторона, идет заполнение как? Слева звезда и справа звезда, а всего надо заполнить пространство количеством символов, указанных в `horizCount`.... вычитаем две звезды, получается `horizCount - 2` .... то есть цикл будет бежать от 0 до 8 при этом НЕ включая 8 (так как написано `i < horizCount - 2`, а не `i <= horizCount - 2`)....... получится 8 итераций 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7........

Comment: @Bodrov, примеры ромбов и треугольников можно увидеть по ссылка в секции связанные вопросы слева

Answer (score 1):

```js
function rect(a, b, char='*', space = ' ') {
  let line1 = Array(a+1).fill().join(char);
  let line2 = char+Array(a-1).fill().join(space)+char;
  let body = b > 2 ? Array(b-2).fill().map(u => line2): [];
  body.unshift(line1);
  if (b>1) body.push(line1);
  return body.join('\n');
}
// с использованием String.repeat
function rect_rep(a, b, char='*', space = ' ') {
  let line1 = char.repeat(a);
  let line2 = char+space.repeat(a-2)+char+'\n';
  let body = b > 2 ? line2.repeat(b-2): '';
  body = line1 + '\n' + body;
  if (b>1) body += line1;
  return body;
}

function rect_loops(a, b, char='*', space = ' ', nl = '\n') {
  let res = '';
  // верхняя линия
  for (let i = 0; i < a; ++i) res += char;
  res += nl;
  if (b > 2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < b - 2; ++i) {
      res += char;
      for (let j = 0; j < a - 2; ++j) res += space;
      res += char+nl;
    }
  }
  // нижняя линяя
  if (b > 1)
  for (let i = 0; i < a; ++i) res += char;
  return res;
}

console.log(rect_loops(7, 3));

console.log(rect_rep(30, 5));

console.log(rect(2, 1));

console.log(rect(1, 1));

let output = document.querySelectorAll('output');
output[0].style['white-space'] = 'pre';
output[0].style['font-family'] = 'monospace';
output[0].innerHTML = rect_loops(28, 5);

output[1].style['font-family'] = 'monospace';
output[1].innerHTML = rect_loops(28, 5, '*', '&nbsp;', '<br/>');
```

```css
body {margin-bottom: 100px;}
.as-console-wrapper {height: 100px;}
output{display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<output></output>
<output></output>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл написать, что без repeat, функций, массивов, объектов. Я ещё не дошел до этого.

Comment: См. функцию rect_loops

Answer (score 0):

Равносторонний треугольник:

```js
var line = 8;  // Quantity of lines
var space = 7; // Quantity of gaps in the first line
var star = 1;  // Quantity of stars in the first line

for (var h = 0; h < line; h++) {
  for (var wsp = 0; wsp < space; wsp++) {
    document.write("&nbsp\n");
  }
  for (var wst = 0; wst < star; wst++) {
    document.write("*");
  }
  space -= 1;
  star += 2;
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Прямоугольный треугольник (вариант 1):

```js
for (var h = 0; h < 8; h++) {
  for (var w = 0; w < h + 1; w++) {
    document.write("*\n");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
document.write("<hr>");
```

Прямоугольный треугольник (вариант 2):

```js
var max = 8;
for (var h = 1; h < 9; h++) {
  // Outputs a star while there is
  // a difference between p and max,
  // while p satisfies the condition p <9
  for (var w = max--; w < 9; w++) {
    document.write("*\n");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
document.write("<hr>");
```